# All Emmet Keyboard Shortcuts In PHPStorm, And Detecting Conflicting Ones

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm, emmet, adobe-brackets

I've been using Brackets for a while, now I've decided to move to PHPStorm. I Loved the emmet menu in Brackets with all selection, navigation, wrapping and incrementing numbers options. now i kinda lost in PHPStorm.

Don't know if there is a menu for emmet in there!!? or maybe there are conflicting keys that i can't work properly. help me with this please.

Comment: **1)** There is no menu for Emmet. Why would someone need it? Could you please tell what such menu do that is not possible in PhpStorm (what is required to be done)? **In any case:** PhpStorm does not implement full 100% set of Emmet features -- it mainly concentrates on statement/tags completion/expanding; Lots of other Emmet features were natively available before that in the same or similar form.

Comment: **2)** *"or maybe there are conflicting keys"* **MAYBE?** WTF is this question? Sounds like you did not even bother to check their help to see how it's done there. **In any case:** there is basically one shortcut: `Tab` (and `Code | Surround with... | Emmet` for actions on selected text)

Comment: LazyOne, Thanks for your somehow kind answer. but how can i add to a number by 0.1 or 1 or 10? that's why i said maybe there is conflict keys. and i found that there are conflicts in **keymap** settings.

Comment: *"and i found that there are conflicts in keymap settings"* -- Please be more specific. Yes, there are some shortcuts that assigned to multiple actions. Thing is: not every action is available in specific context, hence there is no real issues.

Comment: Think about Emmet support in PhpStorm this way: generally speaking out of all section described in http://docs.emmet.io/, only working with Abbreviations (HTML and CSS) and Filters are made into PhpStorm under name of Emmet. Lots of other Emmet actions are either available natively as part of normal editing (merge line, remove tag, match tag pair) or via some 3rd party plugin (like increase number). Sure, some things are missing completely (i.e. Math expressions) or do not work the same way as in Emmet (because they were already there in a different form and users got used to it, e.g. comment)

Comment: Therefore -- please be more specific. if you have specific cases/missing features then name it (with example (preferred) or by describing it using just words) and you should get specific answer: yes/no/workaround. The main reason for missing/differently-working actions is pretty simple: if there is no enough demand for them, then why spend time implementing it. If there is enough votes for specific functionality, then eventually it gets implemented (could take weeks... or could take months of not years for that)

Comment: *"how can i add to a number by 0.1 or 1 or 10?"* As I have mentioned in my first comment: "PhpStorm does not implement full 100% set of Emmet features -- it mainly concentrates on statement/tags completion/expanding" (Emmet website states similar thing). This particular action is not implemented as part of Emmet. BUT, there is a **Shifter plugin** (was around for a looong time, before this functionality was made into Emmet) that can do that and much more (e.g. cycle between true/false and other related keywords).